# JPA merge updating all the object from Relationship graph

Tags: jpa, ejb, one-to-many, cascade

I have a Entity which has a oneToMany relationship with another Entity

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity1", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Entity2> entity2;
```

In Entity2 ManyToOne with Entity1

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY1_ID")
private Entity1 entity1;
```

Now, we have two instance of Entity1. Every instance have only 1 instance of Entity 2. I want to update one Entity1 object along with Entity2, but if I use

```
em.merge(Entity1)
```

it will fire two update statement and update both Entity2. But I want to update only the Entity2 associated with this Entity1.

Please advice, what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Probably its very late reply. But might be useful for someone else.
try using `cascade.PERSIST` and handle update/merge of child entities manually.